# Combination Generator in PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I need to write a script which takes a set of numeric values, for example: "1", "2" and "3" (the total number of values could be limitless)

And return the total of every combination, up to a given total, i.e. 5, therefore the return would look something like:

```
(1),
(2),
(3),
(1, 1),
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 1, 2),
(1, 2, 2)

....
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't understand how the two are related. Can you please explain it a bit better, like where does the 5 come from?

Comment: @Qirel I think the 5 is the top limit of the combination. So the program shouldn't output 1,2,3 because if would add up to 6